# texto ultrapassa o limite desejado

Tags: html5, css3, animação, header, css-hover

Bom eu estou tentando fazer uma animação em css3, só que o texto ultrapassa o limite, eu queria que ele ficasse dentro do objeto, e quando eu tocar no objeto, ele aumentar de acordo, com o objeto. mas ele sai da header

O codigo:

```
    <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
 <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    </head>
    <body>
<header class="inicio">
 <h1>Olá, bom, eu estou tentando aprender, então isso é um teste (obviamente) eu espero que fique bom!! haha.</h1>
</header>
    </body>
</html>

.inicio {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #da8d8b;
  margin: auto;
  transition-property: width height border-radius background-color border border-bottom border-top;
  transition: 2s, 1s, 1s, 2s;
  
}


.inicio:hover {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    background-color: #c97e7b;
    
  
}

h1 {

    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    color: rgba(427, 275, 271, 0.1);
    display: inline-block;
    word-break: break-all;
}

header {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o scale() do css para fazer o texto aparecer do mesmo jeito que a header.
Use o scale(0) para esconder totalmente o elemento e quando passar o mouse sobre a header defina scale(1) para que ele apareça totalmente, adicione uma transição para ficar mais bonito e pronto, no fim você terá algo assim:

```
.inicio:hover h1 {
  transform: scale(1);
}
.inicio h1 {
  // ...
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: 2s;
}
```